# How to add constant to specific columns in tab delimited text linux file

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I have a text file that looks like:

cpDNA 1226 1559 Predicted1
cpDNA 2874 7748 Predicted2
cpDNA 8244 9594 Predicted3

And I would like to add a specific value (77244) to all of the values in columns 2 and 3. The spaces between columns are tabs. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' -v val=77244 '{$2+=val; $3+=val}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\S*/&77244/2;s//&77244/3' file
```

Or you may prefer:

```
val=77244; sed 's/\S*/&'$val'/2;s//&'$val'/3' file
```